# Loop Error in Python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm quite new to Python and I recently started a project using Tk/Tck in the form of `tkinter`. It was a Space Invaders game, the kind that people used to play before the Macintosh came along. The problem was that every time I had a loop to loop through the list of bullets, it would only focus on the first bullet on the screen. Is there a way to change this, and I have this code which goes as follows:

```
def update(self):
        if self.done == False:
            self.canvas.move(self.id, 0, 1)
            pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
            if debug == True:
                #print(pos)
                pass
            if self.hit_enemy(pos) == True:
                canvas.delete(self.id)
                self.done = True
        else:
            pass
```

Is there a way to change this so it removes the value from the list of invaders (the code above is the `update` function on the `Space Invaders` class) instead of keeping it there? Later, it starts to strain my poor old computer, which runs an old GPU. Here's the full code for the `Space Invaders` class:

```
class Space_invader:
    def __init__(self, canvas, colour,pos):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.enemy = bullets
        self.done = False
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,30,20, fill=colour)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 0)
        self.canvas.move(self.id,pos,0)
        self.x = 0
        self.y = -1
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()

    def hit_enemy(self, pos):
        debugself = True

        for i in self.enemy:
            bulletpos = []
            bulletpos = self.canvas.coords(i.id)
            if debugself == True:
                #print(bulletpos)
                print(i)
                print(self.enemy)
            if pos[2] >= bulletpos[0] and pos[0] <= bulletpos[2]:
                if pos[3] >= bulletpos[1] and pos[3] <= bulletpos[3]:
                    self.enemy.remove(i)
                    canvas.delete(i.id)
                    return True
            return False


    def update(self):
        if self.done == False:
            self.canvas.move(self.id, 0, 1)
            pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
            if debug == True:
                #print(pos)
                pass
            if self.hit_enemy(pos) == True:
                canvas.delete(self.id)
                self.done = True
        else:
            pass
```

Is there a way to change/fix both problems? (The second question isn't exactly a problem, but a question) I am, again, quite new to Python.

Comment: And where do you have list of bullets ? I probably see only one bullet in your code: `self.id`.

Comment: Now I see -- you named it `enemy`.

Comment: But what/where is `list of invaders` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong indention in `hit_enemy` and `return False` is run after first bullet.